# Driver Deployment is failing on virtual machine

Tags: c++, driver, wdk, kmdf

I have create sample driver with the help of tutorials, Code contains ,

```
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    DbgPrint("Hello, World");
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n"));
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n"));
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Configured the target machine `VM-8164PR` with `Hardware ID Driver Update` has chosen with the ID `Root/Hello`
When trying to Debug the code in `VS debug option`, 
The Log of `Driver Deployment and VS Debugger` shows it has failed while the `setupapi.dev.log` show the operation was success,

Driver Deployment Log is below..
`Driver_Install_(x64)_(possible_reboot)` log is only adding because of all the other operations logs are showing success and this one failing.

```
<WTT-Logger>
<RTI ID="1959286560" Machine="VM-8164PR" ProcessName="C:\DriverTest\Run\te.exe" ProcessID="3872" ThreadID="3376" BaseTime="2016:2:1 15:10:47:880" Frequency="3112956" />
<CTX ID="384048256" Current="WTTLOG" Parent="ROOT" />

<RTI ID="1242937543" Machine="VM-8164PR" ProcessName="C:\DriverTest\Run\te.exe" ProcessID="3872" ThreadID="3836" BaseTime="2016:2:1 15:10:47:886" Frequency="3112956" />
<CTX ID="8808466" Current="DriverTestTasks::_RunProcess" Parent="WTTLOG" />
<StartTest 
    Title="DriverTestTasks::_RunProcess" 
    TUID="" CA="1094776" LA="1094871" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3836" ProcessId="3872" TimeStamp="76975455169"/>
</Data> <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</StartTest> 
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Description" 
    AttributeValue="Specify a custom binary and command line to be run on the target system.  The path to the binary file that will be executed needs to use environment variables so the path can be resolved on the target computer.  Alternatively the binary file being executed can be in the system path." CA="1102070" LA="1113510" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Category" 
    AttributeValue="Utilities" CA="1105587" LA="1116524" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.DisplayName" 
    AttributeValue="Run custom test binary" CA="1109620" LA="1120885" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Drivers" 
    AttributeValue="true" CA="1113390" LA="1124391" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter" 
    AttributeValue="BinaryPath" CA="1116421" LA="1127795" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter" 
    AttributeValue="Arguments" CA="1120728" LA="1130947" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter" 
    AttributeValue="ExitCodes" CA="1124266" LA="1139980" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter" 
    AttributeValue="WorkingFolder" CA="1127650" LA="1143977" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter" 
    AttributeValue="LogOutput" CA="1130821" LA="1148165" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.Arguments.Description" 
    AttributeValue="Command line arguments that will be specified when the process is created." CA="1139793" LA="1152394" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.BinaryPath.Description" 
    AttributeValue="Path to the binary file that will be executed.  The path needs to use environment variables so it can be resolved on the target computer.  Alternatively the binary file being executed can be in the system path." CA="1143857" LA="1157464" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.ExitCodes.Default" 
    AttributeValue="0" CA="1148058" LA="1160206" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.ExitCodes.Description" 
    AttributeValue="Comma delimited list of valid exit codes for the process.  If the process exits with one of the specified exit codes, the test will be marked as passing.  Otherwise the test will be marked as failing." CA="1152262" LA="1162876" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef> 
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.LogOutput.Description" 
    AttributeValue="Value indicating if console output should be captured and written to the log file.  1 indicates the console output will be captures, 0 indicates the console output will not be captured." CA="1160098" LA="1170213" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>
<MetadataRef 
    Id="WexLogger" 
    Inherit="False" 
    AttributeName="Kits.Parameter.WorkingFolder.Description" 
    AttributeValue="Working folder for the executing process.  This path should use environment variables so it can be resolved on the target computer." CA="1162769" LA="1173985" >
    <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</MetadataRef>

<RTI ID="4169425644" Machine="VM-8164PR" ProcessName="C:\DriverTest\Run\te.exe" ProcessID="3872" ThreadID="1900" BaseTime="2016:2:1 15:10:48:23" Frequency="3112956" />
<Msg 
    UserText="Retrieving parameters..." CA="1515833" LA="1515902" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975877836"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Binary Path: &apos;C:\DriverTest\devcon.exe&apos;" CA="1521079" LA="1521146" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975888886"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Arguments: &apos;&apos;" CA="1527751" LA="1527806" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975894312"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Exit Codes: &apos;0&apos;" CA="1531916" LA="1531960" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975900861"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Capture console output: 1" CA="1562930" LA="1563024" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975904822"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Working Folder: C:\DriverTest\Drivers" CA="1568455" LA="1568515" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975936456"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Executing command line: &quot;C:\DriverTest\devcon.exe&quot; " CA="1577732" LA="1577871" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76975941811"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="devcon.exe Usage: devcon.exe [-r] [-m:\\&lt;machine&gt;] &lt;command&gt; [&lt;arg&gt;...]" CA="1748927" LA="1749499" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976120170"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="For more information, type: devcon.exe help" CA="1825036" LA="1826203" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976121768"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Process exit code: 3" CA="1830867" LA="1831330" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976198451"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Exit code does NOT match a valid passing exit code" CA="1836276" LA="1837335" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976203605"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="The system cannot find the path specified.
" CA="1843984" LA="1844556" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976209592"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<Msg 
    UserText="Process failed to complete successfully" CA="1849722" LA="1850285" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3664" ProcessId="3720" TimeStamp="76976216820"/>
</Data> <rti id="4169425644" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</Msg>
<EndTest 
    Title="DriverTestTasks::_RunProcess" 
    TUID="" 
    Result="Fail" 
    Repro="" CA="1858984" LA="1861192" >
<Data>
<WexTraceInfo ThreadId="3836" ProcessId="3872" TimeStamp="76976223586"/>
</Data> <rti id="1242937543" />
    <ctx id="8808466" />
</EndTest>
<PFRollup 
    Total="1" 
    Passed="0" 
    Failed="1" 
    Blocked="0" 
    Warned="0" 
    Skipped="0" CA="3435531" LA="3435620" >
    <rti id="1959286560" />
    <ctx id="384048256" />
</PFRollup>
</WTT-Logger>
```

setupapi.dev.log Log is

```
>>>  [SetupCopyOEMInf - C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf]
>>>  Section start 2016/02/01 20:40:43.427
      cmd: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.processhost.exe  /ThreadingModel="None" /DefaultAppDomain="false" /DpiAware="false" /role=TestExecution /wexcommunication_connectionid=f402b47f-3bba-43b5-930b-c9da9844cbe5 /wexcommunication_protocol=ncalrpc /wexlogger_connectiondata={wexcommunication_connectionid=2ae81972-900e-4cc3-927b-b0a5a54a99af,wexcommunication_connecttimeout=60000,wexcommunication_protocol=ncalrpc,wexlogger_parent_thread_id=1636} /stackframecount=50
     sto: {Setup Import Driver Package: C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.437
     inf:      Opened INF: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:      Provider: 
     inf:      Class GUID: {78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}
     inf:      Driver Version: 02/01/2016,14.6.29.937
     inf:      Catalog File: Hello.cat
     sto:      {Copy Driver Package: C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.476
     sto:           Driver Package = C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf
     sto:           Flags          = 0x00000007
     sto:           Destination    = C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}
     sto:           Copying driver package files to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'.
     inf:           Opened INF: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:           Opened INF: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000000
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000000
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.cat'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000000
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.inf'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000000
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.sys'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {_commit_file_queue} 20:40:43.595
     flq:                CommitQ DelNodes=0 RenNodes=0 CopyNodes=4
     flq:                {_commit_copy_subqueue}
     flq:                     subqueue count=4
     flq:                     source media:
     flq:                          SourcePath   - [C:\DriverTest\Drivers]
     flq:                          SourceFile   - [WdfCoInstaller01011.dll]
     flq:                          Flags        - 0x00000000
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7663.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7663.tmp' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.cat' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.cat'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.cat' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7674.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7674.tmp' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.cat'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7694.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET7694.tmp' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.sys' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.sys'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.sys' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET76C4.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\SET76C4.tmp' to 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.sys'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                {_commit_copy_subqueue exit OK}
     flq:           {_commit_file_queue exit OK} 20:40:43.741
     sto:           Copied driver package. Time = 250 ms
     sto:      {Copy Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.747
     pol:      {Driver package policy check} 20:40:43.753
     pol:      {Driver package policy check - exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.753
     sto:      {Stage Driver Package: C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.756
     inf:           Opened INF: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:           Opened INF: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:           {Query Configurability: C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.761
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:                Schema extension {78a1c341-4539-11d3-b88d-00c04fad5171} not found.
     inf:                Driver package uses WDF.
     inf:                Driver package 'Hello.inf' is configurable.
     inf:           {Query Configurability: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.767
     sto:           Copying driver package files:
     sto:                Source Path      = C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}
     sto:                Destination Path = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000010
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000010
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.cat'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000010
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.inf'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                CopyStyle      - 0x00000010
     flq:                SourceRootPath - 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}'
     flq:                SourceFilename - 'Hello.sys'
     flq:                TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}'
     flq:           {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:           {_commit_file_queue} 20:40:43.792
     flq:                CommitQ DelNodes=0 RenNodes=0 CopyNodes=4
     flq:                {_commit_copy_subqueue}
     flq:                     subqueue count=4
     flq:                     source media:
     flq:                          SourcePath   - [C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}]
     flq:                          SourceFile   - [WdfCoInstaller01011.dll]
     flq:                          Flags        - 0x00000000
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET771F.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET771F.tmp' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.cat' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.cat'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.cat' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET772F.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET772F.tmp' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.cat'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.inf' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET7740.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET7740.tmp' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile}
     flq:                          Copying 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.sys' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.sys'.
     flq:                          CopyFile: 'C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{305cd262-63fd-6b4f-a4c5-453117383c36}\Hello.sys' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET7741.tmp'
     flq:                          MoveFile: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\SET7741.tmp' to 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.sys'
     flq:                     {_commit_copyfile exit OK}
     flq:                {_commit_copy_subqueue exit OK}
     flq:           {_commit_file_queue exit OK} 20:40:43.851
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE} 20:40:43.851
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 20:40:43.861
     sig:                     Key      = Hello.inf
     sig:                     FilePath = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf
     sig:                     Catalog  = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.cat
!    sig:                     Verifying file against specific (valid) catalog failed! (0x800b0109)
!    sig:                     Error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0x800b0109)} 20:40:43.870
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 20:40:43.872
     sig:                     Key      = Hello.inf
     sig:                     FilePath = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf
     sig:                     Catalog  = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.cat
     sig:                     Success: File is signed in Authenticode(tm) catalog.
     sig:                     Error 0xe0000241: The INF was signed with an Authenticode(tm) catalog from a trusted publisher.
     sig:                {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0xe0000241)} 20:40:43.907
     sig:                Driver package is digitally signed by 'WDKTestCert CodeWork,130983606847203281' (). Signer Score = 0x0F000000
     sig:                Code Integrity State: Unenforced
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     sig:                Validating driver package files against catalog 'Hello.cat'.
     sig:                Verified file 'WdfCoInstaller01011.dll'.
     sig:                Verified file 'Hello.sys'.
     sig:                Driver package is valid.
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.923
     sig:           Signer Score = 0x0F000000
     sig:           Signer Name  = WDKTestCert CodeWork,130983606847203281
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN} 20:40:43.925
     bak:                System restore not required for signed driver package.
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.927
     sto:           Importing driver package files:
     sto:                Source Path      = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}
     sto:                Destination Path = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0
     cpy:           {Copy Directory: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{2335864c-f3cd-2941-a73e-a464e3a28765}} 20:40:43.929
     cpy:                Target Path = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0
     cpy:           {Copy Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.933
     idb:           {Register Driver Package: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.935
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     idb:                Created driver package object 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                Created driver INF file object 'oem4.inf' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                Registered driver package 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0' with 'oem4.inf'.
     idb:           {Register Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.941
     idb:           {Publish Driver Package: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf} 20:40:43.941
     idb:                Opened driver package object 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                Opened driver INF file object 'oem4.inf' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                Activating driver package 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0'.
     cpy:                Published 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\hello.inf' to 'oem4.inf'.
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\hello.inf' ([strings])
     idb:                Indexed 2 device IDs for 'hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0'.
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\hello.inf' ([strings])
     idb:           {Publish Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.952
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END} 20:40:43.952
     sig:                Installed catalog 'Hello.cat' as 'oem4.cat'.
     inf:                Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     sto:           {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.978
     sto:      {Stage Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 20:40:43.980
     ndv:      Doing device matching lookup
     inf:      Opened INF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf:      Saved PNF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.PNF' (Language = 0409)
     sto: {Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000000)} 20:40:43.998
     inf: Opened INF: 'C:\DriverTest\Drivers\Hello.inf' ([strings])
     inf: Driver Store Path: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hello.inf_amd64_0037bf346edeeac0\Hello.inf
     inf: Published Inf Path: C:\Windows\INF\oem4.inf
<<<  Section end 2016/02/01 20:40:44.017
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]
```